# Is there a way that I can automatically add a link to the navigation when a company installs our app?

Tags: managed-package, custom-object

I am a computer programmer at a company that sells data about potential sales leads. We don't use Salesforce, but our customers do use Salesforce. Right now, they buy data from us and then they manually import that data to Salesforce. I have been given the task of developing an app that we can release in the Salesforce App Exchange. The app will automate the import of the data. The app will be a managed package.

We have a lot of data that is not supported by standard Salesforce objects, so I created a custom ImportData object.

After our users have run an import, I want them to see a link in the navigation. I want them to be able to click on the link and see a list of the ImportData objects, in standard format, with standard pagination.

Is there a way that I can automatically add a link to the navigation when a company installs our app? I've never done this before so I don't fully understand the process. Would a link to our custom object appear automatically? Does the Salesforce admin (at the company who is our customer) need to install the link manually? Is there anyway I can automatically add a link, when the app is installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you build a managed package app ,once you create a package you will see a custom link option as shown in screenshot

[image]

> The custom link displays as a Configure link within Salesforce on the Force.com AppExchange Downloads page and app detail page of the installer's organization

Read further on how to use the Configure Custom Links [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=develop_documentation.htm&language=en_US#ConfigureOption).In short you can provide a link to a visualforce where you can throw bunch of links or even add a custom code to fetch and show the count of data imports and other data